# Windows equivalent of $@

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

I use this bash script to set a variable and then `"$@"` to lanch whatever I pass to the script.

```
password=ABC "$@"
```

What is the windows equivalent of `"$@"`?

My attempt of a batch script is:

```
SET password=ABC
start "" "%1"
```

It seems it set the variable and then it stops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing in Cmd.exe "batch" scripts would be `%*`.

At first glance it's the equivalent of Bash's `$*`, not `$@`. However, Windows command lines are single strings, not string arrays – it's up to the final program to dequote and split the command line. This means that `%*` preserves the original quoting exactly as it was input by the user, and there is no need to have something like a "%@".